# How to submit a form on enter that doesn't have a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form whose submit "button" is actually a link.  Is there a way to submit this form automatically on enter, other than attaching an event handler to check for Enter keypresses?  It just seems a little wasteful to me.

Comment: It seems crazy to me to use a link for a submit button. Some browsers submit when enter is pressed, some don't. Users are familiar with how their browser works, messing with the UI is plain annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested in Chrome and Firefox, it appears that pressing enter in a form field will submit it, whether or not a submit button is present.

If you've found a browser where that isn't the case, you may want to try a submit button in a hidden div, or CSS positioned off-screen.

Or stick to conventions and use a submit button :P

Comment: In my experience, firefox will not submit the form on ENTER unless there's a hidden input:submit and chrome will not submit even if there's one but with display:none.

Answer (score 0):

Throw some jquery on there and submit the form with it:

```
$("form#formID").submit();
```

Comment: This is not wrong, but note that it's more work for the library if you put an element name in front of the id value - if there's an id, there should be no need to check the element type ...

Comment: it's also not really clear where you'd put this code to have the form submit on enter

Comment: I know how to submit a form.  The question is about capturing the Enter keypress without resorting to a keypress event handler.